# How can I draw lines inside the bars in charts.js?

Tags: chart.js, line, bar-chart

[image: line]

For example,
I have maximum points for first bar - 16.
100% / 16 = 6,25 % for 1 point.
As a result, in the first bar every 6,25% I need to draw the line.

For the second bar maximum is 6 and for the 3rd maximum is 3.

Comment: Add data example -or- even code-snippet. From first look sound like something complex (No API for this idea - there is option to put pattern inside bars). Chart.js use this idea for groups (Not for "steps" inside the bar himself). https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked-group.html

Also, looks like not so friendly way to show data

Answer (score 0):

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function(chart) {
        var ctx = chart.ctx;

        chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var yAxe = chart.scales[chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].id];
                ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.setLineDash([10, 10]);
                //value
                lineAt = yAxe.getPixelForValue(200);

                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;

                ctx.moveTo(model.x - (model.width / 2), lineAt);
                ctx.lineTo(model.x + (model.width / 2), lineAt);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, Please consider adding some explanation.